# Get the typed object with pattern factory

Tags: c#, interface, factory

see my code :

```
public interface IStructureType
{
    int Longueur { get; set; }
    int Position { get; set; }
    int CompleterCodeBy { get; set; }
}


public abstract class StructureTypeFactory
{
    public abstract IStructureType GetStructureType(string type);
}

public class ConcreteStructureTypeFactory : StructureTypeFactory
{
    public override IStructureType GetStructureType(string type)
    {
       switch(type)
        {
            case "StructureCodeMagasin":
                return new StructureCodeMagasin();

            case "StructureChrono":
                return new StructureChrono();

            case "StructureLotSimple":
                return new StructureLotSimple();

            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("");
        }
    }
}

 public class StructureCodeMagasin : IStructureType
{
    public int Longueur { get ; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int CompleterCodeBy { get { return 2; }  set { CompleterCodeBy = value; }  }

    public void GetCodeMagasin()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

I try to use Factory pattern, but how I can access to method GetCodeMagasin in this example :

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StructureTypeFactory st = new ConcreteStructureTypeFactory();

        var structure = st.GetStructureType("StructureCodeMagasin");

        int longueur = structure.CompleterCodeBy;

    }
```

I can access properties but no method, I would like structure variable will typed StructureCodeMagasin.

Thanks for help

Comment: `I can access properties but no method`, of course, your interface has no methods. It's a little unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve here, but it might be the case that generics would be more appropriate for you.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how use generics method like "WHERE T is IStructureType" for example. Thanks

Comment: I guess you're misunderstanding the Factory pattern. Your factory produces objects implementing the root `IStructureType` interface. Now you want to know what concrete type the created object is of (because you want to access its method that is not part of the interface). Maybe you need some other design pattern here. Or better, describe what are you _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to known which design pattern to use. I've a n Interface IStructureType with some classes like StructureCodeMagasin, StructureBorne..who inherit the interface. Each classes has the same properties but different methods. So I thought factory pattern was a good idea but maybe I'm making a mistake ? Thanks for help

Comment: I think you are trying to force a design pattern which doesn't apply, because *"Each class has the same properties but different methods"*, and you actually want to make use of the methods. And don't put the methods on the interface, because that breaches Liskov (the 'L' in SOLID). For example: *aeroplane* and *car* are both vehicles, both have numbers of doors and wheels, but car can `Drive()` and aeroplane can `Fly()`. You could make them implement the same interface by changing those methods to more generic `Move()`, or accept that they are for different purposes: stop treating as the same.